# Rails filtering by last child attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a problem with active_record query, sorry, I'm new with rails.

I have a model Subscription, it has child SubscriptionVersion, where I keep all info that can be updated.

At API calls, for example get request, I merge data from subscription and current version (`@subscription.subscription_versions.last`) and give that merged hash for response, but I've faced with problem of sorting and filtering by values in that current_version.

When I try do that 
`@subscriptions.joins(:subscription_versions).order('subscription_versions.version')` it takes all version and sort by min value, even if subscription has 5 versions and latest is 5th (current_version).

So ... can anyone give me advice how to generate query for that without adding new field in subscription model `current_version_id`?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want only to return the last subscription_version?

Depending on how the versions are sorted, you could do this (Haven't tested this):

```
@subscriptions.joins(:subscription_versions).order('subscription_versions.version').first
```

or

```
@subscriptions.joins(:subscription_versions).order('subscription_versions.version').last
```

Comment: In that case it just return first/last subscription from sorted collection, but I need that it sorts always by last subscription_version

Comment: Ah then I misunderstood your question. By default, Rails sorts in Ascending order. You can add :desc to sort in descending order like so: 
User.order(email: :desc)

Comment: No, what I want sort instances by ascending, for subscription with 5 versions current_version will 5th, but it put it on top place, because it always had subscription_version with version 1, but I need sort only by latest version

Comment: Because by default Rails uses ascending order, meaning it will go from 1 - 5. Try this: `@subscriptions.joins(:subscription_versions).order('subscription_versions.version DESC')`